# Stripslashes() on array

Tags: php, arrays, stripslashes

I have some problems using stripslashes() on array.

Here is my array :

```
$tabRegion = array(
1=>"Alsace",
2=>"Aquitaine",
3=>"Auvergne",
4=>"Basse-Normandie",
5=>"Bourgogne",
6=>"Bretagne",
7=>"Centre",
8=>"Champagne-Ardenne",
9=>"Corse",
10=>"Franche-Comté",
(...)
21=>"Provence-Alpes-Côte d'Azur",
22=>"Rhône-Alpes",);
```

In order to stripslash, I have adapted this PHP code :

```
foreach ($tabRegion as $key=>$region) {
$tabRegion[$key] = stripslashes($region);
}
```

After in the file, I generate URL with it for example :

```
if (file_exists('../region/$tabRegion[$region]/$fonction/messages/$lecturefichier (...)
```

But the fact is that the last value of the array is always selected ("Rhône-Alpes") by the code... I don't know why.

Do you have an idea? :)

Thank you !

Comment: `if (file_exists('...'))` -- This will always return `FALSE` because the actual variable values will not be interpolated when the code is run. Use double-quotes instead. `if (file_exists("..."))`.

Comment: There aren’t even any backslashes to strip in your example data. And even if there were, you should fix this problem at the source – fix whatever nonsense mechanism is putting them there in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I will work on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using foreach loop then you have to generate url in that loop. 
In that loop you will get each region value 
    $tabRegion = array(
    1=>"Alsace",
    2=>"Aquitaine",
    3=>"Auvergne",
    4=>"Basse-Normandie",
    5=>"Bourgogne",
    6=>"Bretagne",
    7=>"Centre",
    8=>"Champagne-Ardenne",
    9=>"Corse");

```
foreach ($tabRegion as $key=>$region) 
{

 $tabRegion[$key] = stripslashes($region);
 print "<br>".$region;

}
```

Output will be :
    Alsace 
    Aquitaine 
    Auvergne 
    Basse-Normandie 
    Bourgogne 
    Bretagne 
    Centre 
    Champagne-Ardenne 
    Corse

So that,you have to insert following line in that for loop :
    if (file_exists('../region/$tabRegion[$region]/$fonction/messages/$lecturefichier (...)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$region` variable in `foreach` loop and you should know that it is treated like any other variable in your script. So for example:

```
$fruit = 'Banana';    

foreach(array('Tomato', 'Orange') as $fruit) {
    echo $fruit;
}

echo $fruit; // it will output 'Orange';
```

Comment: Thank you barell for your answer, I have understood the idea.